# Test Kafka consumer with Testcontainers and Mockito couldn't invoke consumer in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, mockito, testcontainers

I am trying to setup a kafka consumer and test it with Testcontainers and Mickito. It looks like the producer works fine but the consumer has not been triggered and always gives me:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
helloKafkaService.handleMessage(
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at com.my.kafka.HelloKafkaListenerTestIT.helloKafkaListenerTest
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Here is my service interface HelloKafkaService.java:

```
@Service
public interface HelloKafkaService {
  public void handleMessage(ExampleEvent exampleEvent);
}
```

My consumer: HelloKafkaListener.java

```
@Component
public class HelloKafkaListener {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloKafkaListener.class);
  
  private final HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService;
  
  public HelloKafkaListener(HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService) {
    this.helloKafkaService = helloKafkaService;
  }
  
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "my-topic",
      groupId = "my-topic:HelloKafkaListener")
  public void process(ExampleEvent event) {
    this.helloKafkaService.handleMessage(event);
    log.info("Processing event: " + event.getExampleField());
  }
}
```

My test HelloKafkaListenerTestIT.java:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class HelloKafkaListenerTestIT {
  
  @Container
  public static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.5"));
  
  @Mock
  private HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService;
  
  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, ExampleEvent> kafkaTemplate;
  
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, () -> "test-id");
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, () -> StringSerializer.class.getName());
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, () -> KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
  }
  
  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    Serializer keySerializer;
    Serializer valueSerializer;
  
    var avroConfig = Map.of(
        KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081",
        KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, true,
        KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.USE_LATEST_VERSION, true
    );
  
    keySerializer = new StringSerializer();
  
    valueSerializer = new SpecificAvroSerializer<ExampleEvent>();
    valueSerializer.configure(avroConfig, false);
  
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test-id");
    config.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");

  
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, ExampleEvent> producerFactory =
        new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config, keySerializer, valueSerializer);
    this.kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
 
  }
  
  static {
    kafkaContainer.start();
  }
  
  
  @Test
  public void helloKafkaListenerTest() {
    ArgumentCaptor<ExampleEvent> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ExampleEvent.class);
    ExampleEvent exampleEvent = new ExampleEvent("Hello World!");
    // Confirmed this.kafkaTemplate.send works well
    this.kafkaTemplate.send("my-topic", "key", exampleEvent);
    // Throw the error here:
    verify(helloKafkaService, timeout(5000)).handleMessage(captor.capture());
    assertNotNull(captor.getValue());
    assertEquals("Hello World!", captor.getValue().getExampleField());
  }
  
  @AfterAll
  static void tearDown() {
    kafkaContainer.stop();
  }
```

event.avsc:

```
{
  "namespace": "my.namespace",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ExampleEvent",
  "doc": "A sample event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "exampleField",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why can the consumer not be triggered, if using `@Mock` and `verify`? Is there a better idea to test this?

Comment: Spring-kafka already offers embedded kafka class for testing, why do you need containers? Also, where is your test actually using the listener?

Answer (score 1):

Because `@Mock` just create a mocked instance but this instance will not be managed by the spring context. So `HelloKafkaService` inside `HelloKafkaListener` is still the actual instance but not the mocked one.

You have to use `@MockBean`. The difference is that it will create a mocked instance and also replace the actual bean instance in the spring context with it.

So change to the following should fix the problem :

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class HelloKafkaListenerTestIT {
  
  @MockBean
  private HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService;

}
```

Comment: Hi , Ken Chan, thanks a lot for the explanation. I just tried to use @MockBean, but but still got same error.

Comment: Are you sure `HelloKafkaListener` is really configured properly such that it can deserailize the message into `ExampleEvent` ? Would you add some log at the beginning of the `@KafkaListener` method to verify it is really get called ? If it is not called , it is more than the configuration problem of `HelloKafkaListener` rather than the `HelloKafkaService`

Comment: Hi, Ken Chan, you are right. Looks like HelloKafkaListener has not been called. Let me check the configuration

Comment: Hi, Ken Chan, now if config a Kafka consumer (private KafkaConsumer<String, ExampleEvent> kafkaConsumer;) and use it in my test like this: var records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(20)); which I can see it works (verified the value in records). However, I still not able to trigger the HelloKafkaListener. I found another post you made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783066/how-to-write-unit-test-for-kafkalistener followed the steps, but no luck as well. I am just wondering what's the relationship between my kafkaConsumer and HelloKafkaListener? are they the singleton?

Comment: I should say in my case, I use Testcontainers but your post uses EmbeddedKafka, does this cause the issue?

Comment: `kafkaConsumer ` is the raw kafka client. `KafkaListener` uses it under the cover , and it should be singleton. I feel like your  `@KafkaListener` is not configured properly such that it may not connect to the kafka container created by `Testcontainers`.  I would try to set the breakpoint at `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory#createContainerInstance()` to trobleshoot from there. To be honest , i don't have any clue actually.

Comment: Hi Ken Chan, I did check it again and your are right, I couldn't configure my kafka consumer correctly, since couldn't understand clearly the relationship between kafka consumer and listener. Now, it works after update the consumer configuration. So appreciated your help!